# Type kind error when creating instance of Functor typeclass

Tags: typeclass, functor, purescript

I'm trying to implement `Functor` typeclass instance for a very trivial type `Foo`:

```
data Foo a = Foo a

instance functorFoo :: Functor (Foo a) where
  map fn (Foo a) = Foo (fn a)
```

Purescript gives me not-so-helpful error message:

```
Could not match kind

    Type -> Type

with kind

    Type
```

What does it mean? I'm not yet really familiar with the Kind-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'd still like to find out why does the first version not work. Like how does the Functor typeclass differ from e.g. Semigroup where the first version worked just fine.

Let's look at the definition of the `Functor` type class:

```hs
class Functor f where
  map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It contains `f a` and `f b` types in the type signature of `map` which clearly indicates that `f` is of kind `Type -> Type` (it "carries" another type). On the other hand `Semigroup` clearly relates to plain types of kind `Type`:

```hs
class Semigroup a where
  append :: a -> a -> a
```

So `Semigroup` is a class which can be defined for plain types like `String`, `Int`, `List a`, `Map k v` or even a function `a -> b` (which can also be written as `(->) a b`) but not type constructors which require another type like `List` `Map k` `(->) a` (I have to use this notation here).

On the other hand `Functor` class requires type constructors so you can have instances like `Functor List`, `Functor (Map k)` or `Functor ((->) a)`.

Comment: Thanks for a through explanation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of defining it as:

```
instance functorFoo :: Functor (Foo a) where
```

I need to define it as:

```
instance functorFoo :: Functor Foo where
```

But I'd still like to find out why does the first version not work. Like how does the Functor typeclass differ from e.g. Semigroup where the first version worked just fine.